# VBA - Powerpoint presentation ( and PDF) merging

Tags: vba, pdf, powerpoint

I am using the following code to put together a Powerpoint presentation from many other powerpoint presentations:

```
Sub InsertFromOtherPres()
    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim xlWorkBook As Object
    Dim i, j As Byte
    Dim wbname As String
    Dim sldB, sldE As Byte

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlApp.Visible = True

    On Error Resume Next

    Set xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\----\OneDrive\Desktop\Roli PPT\Book - Pages - Macro.xlsm", True, False)

    On Error GoTo 0

    j = 3

    For i = 2 To 154
        wbname = "C:\Users\----\OneDrive\Desktop\Roli PPT\" & xlWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "K").Value

        sldB = xlWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "L").Value
        sldE = xlWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "L").Value

        ActivePresentation.Slides.InsertFromFile FileName:=wbname, Index:=j, SlideStart:=sldB, SlideEnd:=sldE

        j = j + 1
    Next i

    Set xlApp = Nothing
    Set xlWorkBook = Nothing

    MsgBox "Ready"
End Sub
```

In the excel file in column "K" are the names of the source ppts, and in column "L" are the slide numbers it needs to copy. However I get an error message when the macro gets to a line where the number in column "L" is above 26 (meaning that the slide needed is above 26 in the source ppt)
[image: Run-time error '-213718860 (80048240)': Slides (unknown member) : Integer out of range. 27 is not in the valid range of 1 to 26.]

Could anyone help with this?

Also I am looking for a simple macro that can similarly to the above can copy given pages of a pdf file to another pdf file while also giving where exactly ( page number ) to copy.

Comment: Have you used `Debug.Print` to check the value of `j` when you get the error?

Comment: (Probably also worth checking the values of `sldB` and `sldE` too)  Also - try to stick to just one, specific and focussed, question per question

Comment: For your PDF assembly, you can use JavaScript in Acrobat to accomplish that. https://www.pdfscripting.com/ 
There are also quite a few third-party PDF libraries that let you script PDF assembly in a variety of languages. Here's one that I've used: https://appligent.com/server-software/appendpdf-pro/

Answer (score 0):

I've not had a chance to test it, but this code *should* copy a number of slides from a `Source` presentation to a `Destination` presentation.

It will error out if given invalid numbers (such as *"copy 0 slides"*), and will automatically adjust for overflow (e.g. *"Copy slides 1 to 10 of 7 slides"* or *"insert at slide 20 of 15"*) - both of which I think are errors you may be having.

```
Private Function CopySlidesToPresentation(ByRef Source As Presentation, ByVal CopyStart As Long, ByVal CopySlides As Long, _
    ByRef Destination As Presentation, Optional ByVal InsertAt As Long = -1) As Boolean
    'Source: Presentation to copy from
    'CopyStart: First slide to copy
    'CopySlides: How many slides to copy
    'Destination: Presentation to copy to
    '~~OPTIONAL~~
    'InsertAt: Position to insert at.  If omitted, will insert at the end of the Presentation
    '~~RETURNS~~
    'TRUE if all slides copy successfully
    'FALSE if unable to copy slides

    Dim CurrentSlide As Long

    CopySlidesToPresentation = False
    If CopyStart < 1 Then Exit Function 'Cannot start before the First Slide
    If CopySlides < 1 Then Exit Function 'Cannot copy No or Negative Slides
    If CopyStart > Source.Slides.Count Then Exit Function 'Cannot copy after the Last Slide
    If InsertAt < 1 Then Exit Function 'Cannot Insert before the Presentation starts

    If CopyStart + CopySlides > Source.Slides.Count Then CopySlides = 1 + Source.Slides.Count - CopyStart 'Trim to Presentation Length
    If InsertAt > Destination.Slides.Count Then InsertAt = -1 'Trim to Presentation Length

    On Error GoTo FunctionError

    For CurrentSlide = 0 To CopySlides - 1 'Copy each slide in turn
        Source.Slides(CopyStart + CurrentSlide).Copy
        If InsertAt > 0 Then
            Destination.Slides.Paste InsertAt + CurrentSlide
        Else
            Destination.Slides.Paste 'Put it at the end
        End If
    Next CurrentSlide

    CopySlidesToPresentation = True 'Success!

FunctionError:
    On Error GoTo -1 'Clear the Error Handler
End Function
```